# Why does this code leak?

Tags: c++, ios, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

Well, here again, this time the compiler is showing me a memory error (leak):

> otest(18015,0xacae32c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x194e734:
>   incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified
>   after being freed.
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I'm using clang with ARC activated and STL, this is a C++ file (.cpp).

What I found: If I comment the "delete" line it runs without problems. It makes me wonder who is freeing my allocated memory (cStr).

Btw. This code takes a query string (arg=abc&arg2=asdb) and returns a map whit those values.

```
static map<string, string> getDecodedQueryString( string qs ) {
            map<string, string> r;

            qs = qs+"&";

            char key[100], value[100],  * cStr, *ptr;
            cStr = new char[ qs.length() ];
            memcpy( cStr, qs.c_str(), url.length()-1);
            cStr[qs.length()]=0;

            ptr =  strtok(cStr, "&");
            while ( ptr != NULL && sscanf( ptr, "%[^=]=%[^&]", &key, &value ) == 2) { 
                r[key]=value;
                ptr = strtok(NULL, "&");
            }
            delete [] cStr; //leaking?

            return r; 
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: What is `url.length()` and is that different from `qs.length()`? If `url` is longer than `qs` (which I suspect it might be), you're overwriting past the end of your allocated buffer.

Comment: The error indicates that it is not a leak, but a stale reference to freed memory.

Comment: `new char[ qs.length() ]` doesn't allocate enough memory to hold the terminator. Fix that and start using std:vector and/or std::array and you'll be on your way.

Comment: @GregHewgill, a global variable... and that was the "memory leak" source :S

Comment: @ChetSimpson, you mean `std::string` I think.

Comment: @ChetSimpson in this case, I can not. strtok uses a char *. Not sure if there is an easy tokenaizer solution on C++ (without using Boost)

Comment: @subzero, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c

Comment: @chris std::string could certainly be used and is probably more logical in this case...I just didn't bother looking closely enough to care ;)

Comment: @SubZero There's nothing prevetning you from using the char pointer returned from `string::c_str()` or `vector::data()`

Comment: @ChetSimpson: `c_str()` returns a `const char *` and `strtok()` takes a `char *`, since it modifies the buffer.

Comment: `std::string`, `std::stringstream`, and `std::getline` would work much better here.

Comment: @ChetSimpson, yes, it is, the returned object, the string::c_str() returns a const char *, but the cast (char *) did the job

Comment: @ahenderson same result, more lines

Comment: @subzero, I'm going to say it now: Don't cast your way out of this. Copy the array into a new, non-const one.

Comment: @chris I just tried it, not sure why it worked. I thought strtok modifies the buffer, but not this time

Comment: @subzero, doing `(char *)str.c_str()` is a remnant of C (the cast), and isn't safe. The C++ version of that is `const_cast<char *>(str.c_str())`, but even that isn't appropriate here (or in most other cases). The only way you can do this safely and consistently is by copying the returned data to one you can freely use.

Comment: strtok *does* modify the data. However, because what you do is UB, it may also work, or look like its working. In C++11 you could use string::data, since it, too, is guaranteed to be nul-terminated. (In the meantime, you could just append a NUL to the string since it's only a local variable.)

Comment: @subzero: No, not the same result. It's much harder to get UB using them. And customers like to pay for fewer bugs, not for fewer lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely in these lines:

```
    cStr = new char[ qs.length() ];
    memcpy( cStr, qs.c_str(), url.length()-1);
    cStr[qs.length()]=0;
```

Even without the `memcpy()` (which may have its own problems due to the length of `url`, as I mentioned above in a comment), the `cStr[qs.length()] = 0` writes one byte past the end of the buffer.

If your compiler has `strdup()` available (it's nonstandard, but most do), you can replace this with:

```
cStr = strdup(qs.c_str());
// ...
free(cStr);
```

This saves you from having to mess around with manually allocating bytes, copying them, null terminating in the right place, etc.

Comment: Since you have C++ listed as one of your tags, you may want to consider looking into smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, and `std::weak_ptr` here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Answer (score 3):

```
Str = new char[ qs.length() ];
...
cStr[qs.length()]=0;
```

That write is invalid, it's one past the end of `cStr`. If the allocator stored a checksum right after the allocation, and checks it at delete time, you've just stomped on it.

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of below will do the same thing.

```
std::stringstream ss(qs);
std::string temp;
std::string key;
std::string value;
while(std::getline(ss, temp, '&')) {
   std::stringstream equal(temp);
   std::getline(equal, key, '=');
   std::getline(equal, value, '=');
   r[key] = value;
}
```